# Calculate the size of G=(V,E), E = {A,B|AUB=M}

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let V= Collection of 3 elment subsets of M={1,2,3,4,5}.
Define an Edge here by {A,B}.
Calculate the size of G=(V,E), E={A,B| AUB = M}
With an order(number of vertices) of 5 choose 3 (or V=10).

So far I have this

V={{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{3,4,5},{1,3,4},{1,4,5},{2,4,5},{3,5,1},{1,2,5},{2,3,5},{1,2,4}}

Since AUB=E
an edge can be A={1,2,3} & B= {3,4,5} or {1,2,3},{1,4,5}... etc.

Because the size is |E|, I believe the number of edges would be 10 choose 2, which is 45. I imagine that's the maximum number of possible edges , and not necessarily the total however.

However, the second part of this question asks for a geometric realization of G and drawing a graph with 45 edges seemed a bit excessive to me. 
Any advice? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly,

if you have the set $\{1,2,3\}$, then the only adjacent vertices to it would be those sets containing $\{4,5\}$ which are only $3$ (See it for yourself). Then you would have a graph with $10$ vertices: namely the sets you've found and each vertex being of degree $3$ (this is the number of adjacent vertices). But as every edge is counted twice, you'd get a total of $3*10/2 = 15$ edges.

Trust me, it's not that hard to sketch it :D